# user folders are not set up on login, getting Users\TEMP instead

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

This is on a Windows 10 Pro desktop using local accounts.
During a re-boot I saw a message that said Windows was having trouble connecting to my account.
After the re-boot, I find that I am pointed to C:\Users\TEMP, instead of C:\Users\<name>.
My OneDrive is in File Manager correctly.  Some of my Desktop Icons are present (non-user specific ones, I assume).

Is this a Registry problem?
Can I configure startup to point to the correct Users folder??

Thanks

Comment: This is a common issue going back to Windows XP. What research have you done? Typically it means profile, likely registry, corruption, and you simply create a new profile to fix the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temp profile used when User logs in](https://superuser.com/questions/138402/temp-profile-used-when-user-logs-in)